# testing bytes from a serial port

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to test the data received from a serial port and can't seem to get it right. I need to check if the first byte received in a  packet is 0xBE thus:

```
#ser is instance of pyserial serial object
data=ser.read(5)
print "serial RX: " + binascii.b2a_hex(data)
if data[0] != 0xBE:
    print"wrong value"
```

always prints:

```
serial RX: beef000008
wrong value
```

Even though the binary to ascii print shows that the correct value has been received.

Where am i going wrong in this really basic task?

Thanks,
    Robin.

Comment: well why don't you print out data[0], data[1], data[2] and data[3] and see what is there?

Comment: if I print data[0] I get a 3/4 character which is chr(0xBE) so it's the right value (as confirmed by the bin2ascii also) but serial.read() should return a bytes object in python >= 2.4 according to the docs. is it really a string perhaps?

Comment: I think bytes are sort of strings.  just reading about it now.  but in any case the fix for your situation is to compare data[0] to chr(0xbe) then :)

Comment: you can test the type of your byte using print type(data[0]) to be sure that what you're having is what the documentation says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [pyserial's documentation](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read):

```
Changed in version 2.5: Returns an instance of bytes when available (Python 2.6 and newer) and str otherwise.
```

so I tested:

```
>> bytes(0xbe) == 0xbe
False
```

but if you convert it to int:

```
>> int(bytes(0xbe)) == 0xbe
True
```

as this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901706/the-bytes-type-in-python-2-7-and-pep-358) shows, the [bytes](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-bytes-bytearray-list-tuple-range) type is included by [PEP-3137[3](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3137/)]. It is like a [bytearray](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=bytearray#bytearray) for python3, but just an alias for `str` in [python2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740696/bytes-vs-bytearray-in-python-2-6-and-3).

So, basically, just treat pyserial's output as a `str` while you're doing python2 code.