# I'm doing the cryptopals challenge 5. I'm getting a syntax error in line 5 when trying to run this script in kali linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, syntax, cryptography

> EDIT: I ran the script in IDLE on OSX and it ran without a hitch but when I try to run it in gedit on kali linux I still get the syntax errors. Any guesses?

Here is the syntax error I'm getting:

> ./challenge5.py: line5: syntax error near unexpected token (
>
> ./challenge5.py: defencodeRepeatingKeyXor(s, key):

Here is the full script I'm running:

```py
import binascii

def encodeRepeatingKeyXor(s, key):
    return bytes([s[i] ^ key[i % len(key)] for i in range(len(s))])

x = b'''Burning 'em, if you ain't quick and nimble
I go crazy when I hear a cymbal'''
key = b'ICE'
encodedExpectedY = '0b3637272a2b2e63622c2e69692a23693a2a3c6324202d623d63343c2a26226324272765272a282b2f20430a652e2c652a3124333a653e2b2027630c692b20283165286326302e27282f'
expectedY = binascii.unhexlify(encodedExpectedY)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    y = encodeRepeatingKeyXor(x, key)
    encodedY = binascii.hexlify(y).decode('ascii')
    print(encodedY)
    print(encodedExpectedY)
    if y != expectedY:
        raise Exception(encodedY + ' != ' + encodedExpectedY)
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

> EDIT: I ran the script in IDLE on OSX and it ran without a hitch but when I try to run it in gedit on kali linux I still get the syntax errors. Any guesses?

Comment: Line 5 is an empty line. `defencodeRepeatingKeyXor` is missing. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the link! Also, what do you mean by line 5 is an empty line? Because it's not from what I can tell; line 5 is where the def function is?

Comment: @jww see above edit please

Comment: The error message and the code you show don't seem to quite match up. Based on the error message you're reporting you're missing a space between `def` and `encodeRepeatingKeyXor` (or possibly you've got a unicode character that kind of looks like a space but isn't). On that basis I'm voting to close as a typo

Answer (score 0):

bytes() and b'...' doesn't work like you expect them to do. It's because they're immutable. If you refactor your code with bytearrays it works:

```
import binascii


def encodeRepeatingKeyXor(s, key):
    return bytearray([s[i] ^ key[i % len(key)] for i in range(len(s))])



x = b'''Burning 'em, if you ain't quick and nimble
I go crazy when I hear a cymbal'''
key = b'ICE'
encodedExpectedY = '0b3637272a2b2e63622c2e69692a23693a2a3c6324202d623d63343c2a26226324272765272a282b2f20430a652e2c652a3124333a653e2b2027630c692b20283165286326302e27282f'
expectedY = binascii.unhexlify(encodedExpectedY)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    y = encodeRepeatingKeyXor(bytearray(x), bytearray(key))
    encodedY = binascii.hexlify(y).decode('ascii')
    print(encodedY)
    print(encodedExpectedY)
    if y != expectedY:
        raise Exception(encodedY + ' != ' + encodedExpectedY)
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53754724/11311964) question for further reading..

Comment: I tried what you suggested and I'm still getting the same syntax error.

Comment: I've run the script you gave and it gave a completely different error and i fixed that. Error and the script you gave doesn't match. Could you run the script in linux and copy-paste the error here? 

And how do you run the script? If it is from the command line try this command to see if you really use python 3.x or 2.x: 
     python --version